# Statistical test for one paired observation

Tags: statistical-significance, random-variable, small-sample, paired-data

In [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173392/test-for-equality-of-two-numbers), @whuber writes in his reply that

> If you were willing to assume something about that common distribution (such as it is some Normal distribution--but without knowing or assuming anything about its parameters) then tests exist--even when only a single pair (x,y) is observed (which most people find counterintuitive). Without some kind of assumption, though, your task is hopeless, because you have no information about how much of a difference can be considered "negligible."

I would be interested how such test is carried out (let's assume a normal distribution).

Comment: See this post: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44892/confidence-interval-for-variance-given-one-observation   (and links therein)

Comment: Also see http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/1836 and its comments (which include useful links).